# Installing latest flex-layout for Angular 6

Tags: angular6

Installing Angular-cli 6 seems to work.

```
ng --v
```

> Angular CLI: 6.0.3
>
> Node: 8.11.1 OS: etc...

```
ng new ng6
ng serve
```

All upp and running on localhost:4200

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

No warnings.

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest --save
```

BUT when trying to install flex-layout it seems to load an old version:

> npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/cdk@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14
>   requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself.

Questions:

1. How do I download "latest" flex-layout with correct dependencies for Angular 6?
2. Is Bootstrap grid a more mature option?